# Replacing audio track of the video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I have a video file "MyVideo.mp4" (*.mp4 is not required. It can be in any others formats) and I have an audio file "MyAudio.mp3".
Does anyone have any ideas how to replace an audio track from the video on the audio file "MyAudio.mp3"?

Comment: With Javascript? Why not use Handbrake?

Comment: Yeah, with JavaScript. Functionality is quite simple. User uploads video on the site. Audio track from that video have to replace on the other audio file and than video have to runs on the site with that "MyAudio.mp3" audio track.

Comment: demux+remux is something you would like to do on server side using a software like ffmpeg or similar. Doing this is JavaScript will be non-trivial as you would have to parse and save the file formats manually.

Comment: Wait, do you want your user to be able to download the final video or do you just want to display the video but listen to the audio sound instead of the video's one ? For the later, just mute your video (`yourVideoElement.muted = true`) and use an `<audio>` element to play the sound file then attach some event listeners which will stop the audio on video's `pause` event and start on its `playing` one.

Answer (score 1):

Demultiplexing + remultiplexing ("splitting" + "recombining") is something you would like to do on server side using a software like [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or similar.

Doing this is JavaScript will be non-trivial as you would have to parse and save the file formats manually (you must be able to parse *all* formats you'd support).